# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, discord-api, discord, discord.py

Делал бота добавил разбан все работает кроме EMBED 
Когда пишу .unban бот удаляет сообщения и unbanned человека но EMBED не выводит и напишет в консоль
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

```
async def unban(ctx, *, member): 
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Unbanned', colour = discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if(user.name, user.discriminator)==(member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            emb.set_author(name = member.name, icon_url = member.avatar_url) #ОШИБКА С NAME
            await ctx.send(embed = emb)
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member` - это строка. Откуда у строки поле `name`? В проблемной строке должно быть либо `user.name`, либо `member_name`.